# Elastic search query for composite keys like in SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have below scenario:
Suppose I have a relational table :

```
Key1   Key2  Key3   Value

A       x     v1      0
A       x     v1      10
B       x     v1      5
A       y     v2      7
A       y     v2      2
```

Here I have logical key composite of (Key1, Key2, Key3). Now I need records with the maximum value. So I expect below result corresponding to different logical keys:

```
Key1   Key2  Key3   Value

A       x     v1      10
B       x     v1      5
A       y     v2      7
```

Now I want to write an Elastic Search query for it. Can somebody give me some idea about it ?

Comment: A multi-level `terms` aggregation would do the trick. A more performant approach is to add that compound key as a new field in your document when indexing, so that a single `terms` aggregation can get you what you want.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to add any new field, and I want the full records as you can see in the expected result above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can go with a multi-level `terms` aggregation like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "key1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "key2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "key2"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "key3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "key3"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "doc": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "sort": {"value": "desc"}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually I need to get full documents, but with aggr we can get the doc count or the math function values like max, min or avg.

Comment: I've updated my answer to get you the document with the highest value for the given key.

Comment: Thank you, the query is working, But as I am interested in only one document with max value, so can we avoid sorting and get the max value by some way ? It will be an optimization to the query.